# applying different checkbox filters to show/hide divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently my checkbox filtering is not working, it is making all `grid-cell` div's dissapear when selected.

I would like it to show all categories if nothing is select or if all are selected.

If area: north is selected show all items matching north, if south is selected show all items matching south and if both north and south are selected show all items matching either north or south.

I would also like the same for price if high is selected show high and if both high and low are selected show high and low.

If area selected is north and south and price is low show items containing those 3

e.g so any items that has `data-category-type="high"` or `data-category-name="north"` or `data-category-name="south"`

http://jsfiddle.net/yzyyqqey/3/

```
$('.checkbox').on('click', function (e) {
var $this = $(this),
    $links = $('.checkbox');

if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
    $this.removeClass('selected');
} else {
    $this.addClass('selected');
}

$('.grid-cell').hide();
if ($(".checkbox:checked").length > 0) {
    // any one is checked
    $.each($links, function (k, v) {
        $this = $(v);
        if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
            anySelectedCheckbox = true;
            var cat = $this.data('categoryType');
            var nam = $this.data('categoryName');
            $('.grid-cell:has(div[data-category-type="' + cat + '"],div[data-category-name="' +nam+' "] )').show();
        }

    });
} else {
    // none is checked
    $('.grid-cell').show();
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, try this.
Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjobs/yzyyqqey/21/)
Another mistake is you had high set for all 4 cells.

```
$('.checkbox').on('click', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        $links = $('.checkbox');

    if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
        $this.removeClass('selected');
    } else {
        $this.addClass('selected');
    }

    $('.grid-cell').hide();
    if ($(".checkbox:checked").length > 0) {
        ApplyAllFilters();
    } else {
        // none is checked
        $('.grid-cell').show();
    }
});

function ApplyAllFilters()
{
    var selectedPricesFilterQry = $(".checkbox.priceFilter:checked").map(function() {
                 return '[data-category-type=' + $(this).data('categoryType') + ']';
              }).get()+''

    var selectedAreasFilterQry = $(".checkbox.areaFilter:checked").map(function() {
                 return '[data-category-name=' + $(this).data('categoryName') + ']';
              }).get()+''
   var filteredResults = {};
    if(selectedPricesFilterQry != '') 
        filteredResults  = $('.grid-cell').filter(selectedPricesFilterQry);
    else
        filteredResults  = $('.grid-cell');
    if(selectedAreasFilterQry != '') 
        filteredResults = $(filteredResults).filter(selectedAreasFilterQry);
    $(filteredResults).show();
}
```

Comment: works really well! one things I would like to add is that if north + high and low is selected it would show all items that are either high or low and in north, currently if those are selected it will show all items, and some will be high and south for example.

Comment: I did not follow, but along as you understand now hot to use it, please go head and change as you need. Also don't forget to accept it as answer if it helps your case.

Comment: so currently if you select price 'high' + 'low' and area 'north' it will show all items. It should only show the items from the north with a price of high or low.

Comment: Updated the answer to fit your needs where it applies (high or low) and (north or south)

Comment: if 'north' or 'south' is selected it shows no results, if north is selected it should show the 1 results that has north.likewise if south is selected it should show the 1 result that has south. High and low seem to work though, so close!